# Cross-correlation of multidimensional time-series and Python function for computing it

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, cross-correlation

So far I know, the cross-correlation of two time-series $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ for which $N$ observations are available is given by $r^N(\tau)=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{t=\tau+1}^Na(t-\tau)b(t)$, where $\tau$ indicates the time-lag.
However, I am not sure how to cross-correlate two multi-dimensional time-series.
For instance, let $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ two multidimensional time-series of dimension $q$ and $p$, respectively, and assume that I have $N$ observations that I arranged in a matrix form as it follows

\begin{equation}
        x^{N}:=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        x_1(1) & \dots &  x_q(1) \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        x_1(N) & \dots &  x_q(N)
    \end{bmatrix}\,,
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
        y^{N}:=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        y_1(1) & \dots &  y_p(1) \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        y_1(N) & \dots &  y_p(N)
    \end{bmatrix}\,.
\end{equation}

My instinct would suggest that the cross-correlation $R_{xy}(\tau)$ between $x^N$ and $y^N$  is given by

\begin{equation}
        R_{xy}(\tau)=
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=\tau+1}^N x_1(t-\tau)y_1(t) & \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=\tau+1}^N x_1(t-\tau)y_2(t) & \cdots & \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=\tau+1}^N x_1(t-\tau)y_p(t)] \\
            \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=\tau+1}^N x_2(t-\tau)y_1(t) & \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=\tau+1}^N x_2(t-\tau)y_2(t) & \cdots & \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=\tau+1}^N x_2(t-\tau)y_p(t)] \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=\tau+1}^N x_q(t-\tau)y_1(t) & \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=\tau+1}^N x_q(t-\tau)y_2(t) & \cdots & \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=\tau+1}^N x_q(t-\tau)y_p(t)]
        \end{bmatrix}\,.
    \end{equation}

Is it correct?

Also, is there any `Python` function that would allow me to compute the cross-correlation between $x^N$ and $y^N$? If so, what's that function name?

Comment: There's an inconsistency--perhaps it's a typographical error, or maybe it's what you're trying to ask?  In the univariate formula you have not included a factor of $1/N.$ As far as Python functions go, note that every entry in $R_{xy}(\tau)$ is $1/N$ times one of your $r^N(\tau),$ so if you know of a Python function to compute the latter, you're good to go.

Comment: It was a typographical error. I added the term $1/N$ in the univariate formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summation indices should be from $\tau+1$ to $N$, assuming 1-indexed series, and the cross-correlation matrix looks fine. At least in [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) library, which is a popular tool for time series workloads, there isn't any function to calculate a sample cross-correlation matrix with $\tau=[0,N-1]$ entries, which would be a 3D tensor.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your answer to both the questions. Yes, I am aware that $R_{xy}(\tau)$ is a tensor. And thanks also for pointing me to statsmodel library that I was not aware of. Nevertheless, it seems that I must implement my own function for building up such a cross-correlation tensor $R_{xy}(\tau)$.

Comment: Regarding the text, there were a typo that is now correct.  The summation now goes from $t=1$ to $t=N$. I used the same formulation of cross-correlation that you can find here: http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:316456/FULLTEXT02#:~:text=A%20model%20error%20model%20is,model%20contains%20the%20zero%20model. See for example (4) in the cited paper.

Comment: If you have $N$ samples for both series, the summation can't start with $t=1$ unless you make assumptions over $x(-t)$

Comment: Correct. I have fixed the issue. Thanks again.